# Is there a simulation package for open quantum system dynamics using negative decay rate?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, resource-recommendations, density-operator, software, open-quantum-systems

Consider the following situation: the model is described by a single qubit and the density matrix evolution is governed by the [Lindblad equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindbladian).
${\displaystyle {\dot {\rho }}=-{i \over \hbar }[H,\rho ]+\sum _{i=1}^{N^{2}-1}\gamma _{i}\left(L_{i}\rho L_{i}^{\dagger }-{\frac {1}{2}}\left\{L_{i}^{\dagger }L_{i},\rho \right\}\right).}$

I want to ask whether there is a simulation package when the decay rate $\gamma_{i} <0.$ I know that the standard open quantum system [Qutip.](https://qutip.org/docs/latest/apidoc/functions.html) has the simulation but requires $\gamma_{i} \geq 0.$
Are there any packages to simulate the open quantum system when the decay rate is negative?

Any ideas or comments are welcome and very appreciated

Comment: What are you trying to simulate physically here? I am not an expert on open quantum systems but wouldn't a negative $\gamma_i$ imply that the system and environment spontaneously unmix, against the second law of thermodynamics?

Comment: Yes, this is true, but I can just set it to be negative and solve the pde. For example, suppose I have a single spin system and there is a decay rate \gamma<0, and I want to solve the expectation value of it.